# MongoDB is not showing in my local service

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I was trying to [co](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmCcO.png)nnect node.js to mongodb with the help of mongoos but I got a lot of errors and when I tried to solve the error, I saw that MongoDB is not showing in my local service, can you guys? can you guys guide me why this is happening

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell why this is happening, but the solution is to install the service:

```
mongod --install --config <filename>
```

See [mongod.exe](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/)